# Connection String for Azure Web Job that updates an Azure Database connected with a WebAPI project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, connection-string, azure-webjobs

I have a functioning web api project running in azure using the following connection strings:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-CatalogAPI-20160227031830.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-CatalogAPI-20160227031830;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="ProdStoreEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DbCache.csdl|res://*/DbCache.ssdl|res://*/DbCache.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=ProdStore;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

When I publish this project, in the settings tab I use the connection string of my Azure Database that looks like this.

```
Server=tcp:{name}.database.windows.net,1433;Database=ProductDatabase;User ID={user};Password={your_password_here};Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

This all works fine.

I then created a web job by right-clicking my web api project in visual studio and selecting Add -> New Azure Web Job Project.

Inside my web job project I make a solution reference to my web api project and write some code that uses a repository in my web api project.

I add the exact same connection strings from my web api project to my web job project and everything works fine locally. When I publish the whole thing to Azure though, I get this error.

> Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

My question is, what type of connection string will I need inside my Azure Web Job project? I am assuming it will need a reference to the Azure database somewhere but when I try that I get this error.

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.UnintentionalCodeFirstException: The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First development.  This will not work correctly. To fix this problem do not remove the line of code that throws this exception. If you wish to use Database First or Model First, then make sure that the Entity Framework connection string is included in the app.config or web.config of the start-up project. If you are creating your own DbConnection, then make sure that it is an EntityConnection and not some other type of DbConnection, and that you pass it to one of the base DbContext constructors that take a DbConnection. To learn more about Code First, Database First, and Model First see the Entity Framework documentation here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394715

Comment: Have you found a solution to this yet? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server instance that you are connected to needs to allow other Azure services in the same subscription. It will not allow connections from a different subscription, just go to the configuration of your SQL Server and make sure to verify that "Windows Azure Services" is set to YES under IP configuration. If this still fails, you probably have an error in your connection string.

username is usually user@servername and don't forget the password :)

Comment: Hi Pedro, thanks for the answer but Windows Azure Services were already enabled. I have tried all suitable connection strings with no luck, at a bit of a loss now.

Comment: Whenever I'm doing work against Azure SQL, I usually open up the tab "SQL Object Explorer" in Visual Studio (use CTRL+Q to find it) and then connect to the database in Azure. Then I right-click on the database, and select "Properties" and I just copy the entire connection string to my configuration - that always works for me. Without looking at your code, I couldn't be more specific, sorry